# How to pull a python package from a repo using buildout?

Tags: python, svn, buildout

I have a pre-rolled bootstrap script that creates a buildout.cfg for my wsgi-based framework. Buildout is run with this initially to create the necessary paste directory structure. I then pull my code from the VCS repo into the src directory, and a buildout.cfg specific to whatever env I'm deploying to along with a few other .py static data files. Then I run buildout again.

Running buildout twice is pretty wasteful from my pov. Is there a way to do an export from subversion from within buildout into my project source dir and also arbitrary files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [`mr.developer`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer) to grab a local checkout:

```
[buildout]
extensions = mr.developer
auto-checkout = yourpackage

[sources]
yourpackage = svn http://url.to/repository
```

Now `mr.developer` will check out `yourpackage` as part of the buildout run, into `src/`, run it's `setup.py` to make it a development egg, and tell buildout it's available as such. Now buildout will use that local copy to satisfy any `yourpackage` requirement.

If your svn package is not a python egg, simply add `egg=false` to it's `sources` entry, and `mr.developer` won't look for a `setup.py` to run.

Alternatively, you can just use [`iw.recipe.cmd`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/iw.recipe.cmd/0.3) to simply run the `svn` command:

```
[yourpackage]
recipe = iw.recipe.cmd
cmds = 
   svn export http://url.to/repository
```

Comment: Can mr.developer export instead of co to avoid the svn cruft?

Comment: @user1561108: No, use [`iw.recipe.cmd`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/iw.recipe.cmd/0.3) to run `svn export` instead in that case.